# Record audio inside docker container from Ubuntu host

Tags: docker, ffmpeg, pulseaudio

I have a basic `Dockerfile` as follows:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update \
        && apt-get install -y pulseaudio alsa-utils alsa-base ffmpeg
```

On my host, I am able to record an audio file as follows:

```
ffmpeg -f pulse -i default -f wav out.wav
```

I would like to do the same inside the docker container.

How do I go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: A design goal of Docker is to isolate containers from details of the host physical devices; you can't do this without some involved setup.  If you need to access host devices like this, Docker makes it significantly harder.  Is there a specific reason you want to use Docker for this?

Comment: @DavidMaze: I have a containerized application that uses custom C++ libraries that aren't installed on my host yet.

If there is any other way to get access to audio stream from the microphones, I would appreciate a reply.

Thanks.